# Using strided iterator to find unique arbitrarily-size tuples in Thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I'm trying to write Thrust code that finds unique tuples in a collection, but with one important caveat: the application should be able to handle tuples of arbitrary dimensions i.e. unknown at compile-time. Furthermore, the size of the tuple may exceed 10. These two considerations rule out the thrust tuple. As such I've tried to represent the tuple in structure of array (SoA) form using the stride iterator implementation shamelessly ripped off from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42235487/181783), as shown below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>

typedef unsigned short ushort;

template<typename Iterator>
struct StridedIterator
{
    typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type difference_type;

    struct StrideFunctor : public thrust::unary_function<difference_type,difference_type>
    {
        difference_type m_stride;

        StrideFunctor(difference_type stride ): m_stride( stride )
        {
        }

        __host__ __device__
        difference_type operator()(const difference_type& i) const
        { 
            return m_stride * i;
        }
    };

    typedef typename thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>                   CountingIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::transform_iterator<StrideFunctor, CountingIterator>  TransformIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::permutation_iterator<Iterator,TransformIterator>     PermutationIterator;

    typedef PermutationIterator Type;

    StridedIterator( Iterator startIter , Iterator endIter , difference_type stride )
        : m_startIter( startIter )
        , m_endIter( endIter )
        , m_stride( stride )
    {
    }

    Type begin() const
    {
        return PermutationIterator( m_startIter , TransformIterator( CountingIterator(0) , StrideFunctor( m_stride ) ) );
    }

    Type end() const
    {
        return begin() + ( ( m_endIter - m_startIter ) + ( m_stride - 1 ) ) / m_stride;
    }

    Iterator        m_startIter;
    Iterator        m_endIter;
    difference_type m_stride;
};

int main()
{
    // AoS version
    /*
    2 , 1 ,   -- unique
    1 , 2 ,   -- unique
    1 , 1 ,   -- unique
    1 , 1 ,
    1 , 3 ,   -- unique
    2 , 2 ,   -- unique
    3 , 1 ,   -- unique
    2 , 1 ,
    1 , 2 ,
    1 , 1 ,
    2 , 2 ,
    2 , 2
    */

    // 'SoA' -- twelve 2-tuples, 6 of which are unique
    std::vector<ushort> input{
                        2 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 1 ,   2 , 2 , 
                        1 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 1 ,   2 , 2
                    };

    thrust::host_vector<ushort> hData = input;
    ushort dim = 2;

    thrust::device_vector<ushort> data = hData;
    typedef thrust::device_vector<ushort>::iterator Iterator;

    StridedIterator<Iterator> stridedIter( data.begin() , data.end() , dim );
    auto iter = thrust::unique( stridedIter.begin() , stridedIter.end() );

    std::cout << stridedIter.end() - stridedIter.begin() << std::endl;
    std::cout << iter - stridedIter.begin() << std::endl;
}
```

Unfortunately instead of getting the value of 6 post call to `thrust::unique` I'm getting 9. Please advise.

Comment: There are not 6 unique input sequences in the sample input to your code. Are you sure you actually understand what thrust::unique does?

Comment: No @talonmies there are 6. Please point out the 9 unique sequences. You should be so quick to vote down and close questions.

Comment: No -- read the documentation for thrust::unique "For each group of *consecutive* elements in the range [first, last) with the same value, unique removes all but the first element of the group". An  input sequence of "1,2,1,2,1,2" will be unchanged by thrust::unique. An input sequence  of "1,1,1,2,2,2" will be changed

Comment: I see. It operates on sorted sequences. Now I remember. But I still stand by what I said. True to your profile you are too quick to vote down and close questions. Remember back in the day when you were new to CUDA and liable to make mistakes. Well some people are where you were back then. The eagerness with which you vote down and try to close questions does not make SO welcoming to people who are new to CUDA. And I've done my homework and put weeks into studying CUDA, yet I will make mistakes *because I am new to CUDA*.

Comment: I cut and pasted your code, compiled it, ran it, then added my own diagnostics, then realized the problem, then came here and posted my comments. Don't *you* be so quick to jump to conclusions. Particularly when the entire question could be answered by atually reading some documentation (which I also did before posting)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kzJghpvQ in case you are interested

Comment: Yes because you've been using CUDA for years! And I for well ... a few weeks. But I have printed and read the docs,, read 4 different books (I'm not exaggerating) and watched dozens of videos from the gpuconf (_I'm now sick of them_) and I understand much much more than I did when I started. But newbies *will* make mistakes and that's where you come in. You'd be a lot more helpful if you just pointed out what I'm doing wrong instead of suggesting that I've put in no effort at all. I am making a fuss because this is the 2nd time you've instantly downvoted and tried to close my CUDA question.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three problems here:

1. While the basic functionality of the strided iterator you have adapted is correct, the data you are providing it with is in the incorrect order. If you print the value of the iterator as posted in your code, you will see the following:

   2
   1
   1
   3
   1
   2
   1
   1
   3
   1
   2
   2

   The iterator is skipping every second element in the input, exactly as you are instructing it, which is (I guess) not what you intended given the data written in the comments in your code.
2. In the preamble in your question, you talk about tuples. However there is nothing in your code which imparts any tuple-like behaviour. The comparison operator being used by thrust on your iterator will be `thrust::equal_to<ushort>`. All comparisons will be performed on every odd entry of the input sequence you supply, nothing more.
3. The `thrust::unique` algorithm is a stream compaction routine which removes successive results which compare identically. So the expected `thrust::unique` output in your code is

   2
   1
   3
   1
   2
   1
   3
   1
   2

   which has 9 elements, exactly as your code is calculating.

If you change the data order in the input of your code to something which reflects what you appear to be trying to do, you will have the strided iterator emitting

2
1
1
1
1
2
3
2
1
1
2
2

which `thrust::unique` will compact to

2
1
2
3
2
1
2

which has 7 elements. However, as noted above, none of the code you posted is capable of performing the operation which you describe in words in your question.

Comment: Thanks. Rather than continue to try to create an iterator (my previous attempt failed) I'm going to change tack and solve the problem in 3 steps. (1) Implement a kernel that compares tuples in order create what's labelled as the "input stream" in Fig 2 of the paper http://maverick.inria.fr/Publications/2007/RAH07a/gpuReduction.pdf (2) Use CUB or thrust to perform a prefix sum from the "input stream", the (3) Implement another kernel that uses the prefix sum to copy unique tuples into a target buffer.